# Restoring a part of a production db backup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql, restore

Recently an object and its associated objects(maybe 600 rows in a bunch of tables) were deleted from my production. I have a backup of my data from back when the data was mostly there, and I would like to restore it.

What would be the cleanest/easiest way to do this?

This is a mysql dump so I can easily restore to my dev box, but then what? I am hoping for a command or 2 that generates either SQL or ruby code i can pop into a migration.

Edit: Just came across https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump looks promising

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using seed_dump. Despite it being undocumented, it can dump arbitrary relations and not just entire models, so all I had to do was assemble the right relations and dump them in the rails console with `SeedDump.dump(<relation>, <options>)` to get a seeds file of just the rows I wanted, which I could then restore.